# Sharepoint Cross Site Header using user control

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am developing a Cross site Header across site collection in a web application... For Eg:- I have a Publishing site called http://sdw1999:1234 as my publishing portal and http://sdw1999:1234/sites/team as my team site. I am using a user control to display the TopNavBar of my publishing site in team site on feature activation where scope is site. But the thing is since im using PortalSiteMapProvider, whatever code i write its taking the current site  corresponing to the site in which im activation the feature. But i want publishing site's TopNavBar. so Please someone help me to solve this problem. Some Piece of code would be really helpfull. n for this I have created a class called CrossSitenvaProvider which inherits portalsitemapprovider and im referring to this Custom Provider by  adding a provider in web.config...Everything is almost done but the thing is fetching the nodes...Plz do help me. Im really stuck

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share navigation between sites if they are part of different site collection.

You can do this manually without creating any control

- Activate the Publishing Feature on your Team site.
- Go To Site Settings - > Navigation Settings in your Team Site
- Here you can manually create the links in your top navigation which refer to the links in your Publishing site site collection.